# How to avoid a user from writing specific info in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have this scenario, we have a userA visiting another userB's profile and he clicks on follow. Once he follows userB we want him to write to Firebase and add to userB's followers: { userA: true }... looking at rules I understand we can authenticate the user, but how do we make sure once he is authenticated that he can only write to userB's followers only his userId - being userA without tampering the data and maybe writing userC.

Does authentication give us userA and we can make sure the write can only equal auth.userA for the userId or is it randomly generated and not be the same as the main userId we are using in general for the user?

Also, if the auth.userId can be accessed from their documents can we also call auth.username to grab the authenticated username to make sure they dont write somethign outside of their username?

Here is an example of the data structure:

following
   username
   userid
   date

I am trying to have the user only be able to write their userId and username to following.

```
Map<String, Object> payload = new HashMap<String, Object>();
payload.put("uid", "uniqueId1");
payload.put("some", "arbitrary");
payload.put("data", "here");
TokenGenerator tokenGenerator = new TokenGenerator("<YOUR_FIREBASE_SECRET>");
String token = tokenGenerator.createToken(payload);
```

Does it have to be "data" or can it be "username", "tester" ?

Comment: Answer below. For a next question: you will find that you get answer faster if you include more than just a description of your data structure in your question. For example: most of us find the little diagram I have on your data structure faster to scan than a description of that data structure.

Answer (score 1):

So it sounds like you want to have this structure:

```
followers
   <uid>
     <follower_uid>: true
```

And you want to allow only the user with `follower_uid` to write the value.

This can be done with the following security rules.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "followers": {
      "$uid": {
        "$follower_uid": {
          ".write": "auth.uid == $follower_uid"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I recommend that you read the [Firebase documentation on security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/), which covers this and many more scenarios. It's a bit of a read, but well worth the time.

Comment: Thanks Frank, for setting up my own extra auth methods though, I added some code above for the example, can I run it like that, for payload.put("username", "testuser") Then call auth.username for the check?